# How to get user input in fopen

Tags: c, input, fopen, scanf

Probably obvious, but even my clever "how to c" book doesn't really help me here. I just started with C programming, so sorry if the answer eludes me.

I use `fopen("%s.txt", "w+")` in order to save a textfile. However I have no idea how the user can input a string for %s. I tried it with scanf and other variations. But nothing worked yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include<string.h>

char filename[255];
FILE *fp;
scanf("%s",filename);
strcat(filename,".txt");
fp=fopen(filename,"w+");
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still need the .txt at the end after %s. :(

Comment: I have just added a line which solves this. You also have to add #include<string.h> in order to use strcat.

Comment: Thanks a ton, dude. Works :)